# Why do I get StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow, infinite-loop, tostring

This is my parent class with two methods named `toString`. The one with the parameter is used in the child class.

```java
public abstract class Army {
    private String commander;
    private int soldiers;
    private int guns;
    private int horses;
    private int officers;
    // getters & setters
    public Army(){
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Army{" +
                "commander='" + commander + '\'' +
                ", soldiers=" + soldiers +
                ", guns=" + guns +
                ", horses=" + horses +
                ", officers=" + officers +
                '}';
    }

    public String toString(String type) {
        var result = toString();
        return result.replace("Army", type);
    }
}
```

This is my child class, where I am using the `toString(String type)`method from the parent class inside the `toString` method of the child class:

```java
public class PanzerArmy extends Army {
    private String tanks = "tanks";

    public String getTanks() {
        return tanks;
    }

    public void setTanks(String tanks) {
        this.tanks = tanks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString("PanzerArmy") +
                " tanks='" + tanks + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

When I try to display object of child class I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: You made recursion in ```toString``` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Your `PanzerArmy.toString()` you call `Army.toString(String)`, which in turn calls `toString()`. You might expect `Army.toString()` to be executed here, but since you overrode it in `PanzerArmy` (and the current object is of type `PanzerArmy`) it will call `PanzerArmy.toString()`. .. which will call `Army.toString(String)` and start the whole jazz again, in a never ending recursion. Eventually the JDK decides that it's got enough of this and bails.

A better solution would be to make the `toString()` in `Army` abstract and *only* implement `toString(String)`.

Alternatively you could use something like `getClass().getSimpleName()` to get the short name of the current class and immediately use that instead of having to tweak `toString()` for each subclass.

Comment: Another suitable solution can be to create an accessory method `_toString()` in `Army.class` that actually creates the string and handles all the operations that must be performed by every `toString` method and use it on the one overridden and on the adjunctive method.
In this way, no recursion should happen.